# How to use WebP format in another browers?

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, audit, webp

I use google audits for speedup my app.
So google audit says - "it's time to use .webp images!". Okay, let's do that. But...
Mozilla firefox not supported it. So, I turn on WebPJS and it helped. But...

I have DOM-element:

```
<img src="image.webp" srcset="image-480.webp 480w, image-768.webp 768w, image-1024.webp 1024w" alt="alt" titile="title"/>
```

WebPJS replace src-attribute but don't touch srcset-attribute. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

picture element is what you need:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset='image-480.webp' type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 480px)">
  <source srcset='image-768.webp' type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset='image-1024.webp' type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 769px)">
  <source srcset='image-480.jpg' type="image/jpg" media="(max-width: 480px)">
  <source srcset='image-768.jpg' type="image/jpg" media="(max-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset='image-1024.jpg' type="image/jpg" media="(min-width: 769px)">
  <img src="image-1024.jpg"  />
</picture>
```

Above code shall:

- load webp image for browser where picture attribute and webp image is supported
- load jpg for browser where picture attribute is supported but not webp
- load image-1024.jpg for browser where picture attribute isn't supported

Can I Use : [picture](https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture)  [webp](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with an `onError` as fallback? Something like

`<img src="image.webp" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='image.png'">`

Did you seen this [kind of webp serving](https://www.itnota.com/serve-webp-image-format-fallback/)? Maybe usage of `<picture>` will do the job?

Comment: That's going to be pretty nasty for performance for everything except Chrome. It will add an extra HTTP request for every image.

Comment: @Quentin could you please explain it a bit further? Afaik it makes an additional request only in case of error... Am i wrong?

Comment: And the error will occur in everything except Chrome.

Comment: you are right, yes. Everywhere, where webp isn't supported, there wil be an error. But nevertheless i would firstly measure how this additional request influences the whole performance... And, btw. it isn't only Chrome - Opera and the most mobile browsers do understand webP. So i would inspect the visitor browsers too...

Comment: Unfortunately, WebPJS don't work with <picture> and srcset-attributes.
Moreover, WebPJS use base64 encode for images. I think if I have 10 images of 4 srcset-attribute each on my app, it will be 50 links. If every link encode... HTML-code will grow to unreal measure!
I think in browsers that don't support webp we need use jpg-format.